# Importerror in pycharm

Tags: python, importerror

I just installed the textblob package in python. All works fine. However when I enter:

```
from textblob import TextBlob as tb
```

My pycharm editor still gives an importerror:

```
ImportError: No module named textblob
```

But in cmd screen I have:

```
"Succesfully installed TextBlob ..."
```

Any thoughts on what could go wrong here?

Comment: Follow this link: It might help you  http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html#installing-upgrading-from-the-pypi

Comment: You have to ensure, that you use the correct and the same python Interpreter in cmd mode and in pycharm

Comment: To add to @bierschi comment its under preferences > project: <project name> > project interpreter

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not installed in your env. In Pycharm, Take the cursor to package name use alt+enter.it will give a message to install the package. Install the package (it will take some time as it will download from internet) Also it will index the whole package.

It might also happen that you are not configured project interpreter properly. Go to File menu 'Default Setting'  Look in left side bar for project interpreter check in right side if its there. If yes, it will show the package installed here.